# Clearing SharePoint Online Distributed cache?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, cache, distributedcache

I have a spfx webpart that I recently deployed a quick UI update to. Essentially, I changed a dropdown to be multi-select instead of single select. For hours after deploying my update, half my users continued to see the old version of the webpart on our page, half see the new one. When my users continually refreshed, sometimes they would get the old version, sometimes the new version, sporadically, back and forth. This happened even in Incognito and InPrivate browsing sessions - so it seems to indicate a server cache of sorts on the SharePoint side of things.

I've noticed this behavior multiple times after deploying a new version of a web part. Is there a way to get SharePoint Online to clear this distributed cache, or whatever is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Did you update the version number when updating your web part?

Comment: @CallumCrowley yes, and the new version was added to the site in question.

Comment: It's likely that the files are being cached in the user's browser cache. If they do a hard refresh of their cache, it should resolve the problem. SharePoint Online, works very differently under the hood than SharePoint Server. It's highly unlikely that the issue you're encountering has anything to do with the legacy distributed cache service.

Comment: @CallumCrowley hard refresh was the first test. It's not a browser caching problem. Reproduced on a newly spun up VM that had never touched SharePoint. Reproduced on my phone that had never touched that SharePoint site. Incognito windows, InPrivate windows, cleared browser data, etc. The problem persisted for a few hours. Refreshing would randomly load new OR old versions sporadically - not just the old version. It might not be the same legacy distributed caching service, but something equivalent on the server side of things.

Comment: Did you check in the sppkg file after deployment? Failing that, I would put a ticket in with Microsoft support. Actual server side issues are largely out of our control, being SaaS.

Comment: Any luck with this? I've run into this as well. My current solution is to remove the webpart from the Apps store, and redeploy it with a new Guid, like in this article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-multiple-instance-of-spfx-webpart-in-same-app-catalog/

I'm wondering if it is because I am using the same tenant for my workbench?

Comment: @user232 No, either give it enough time or use your solution. It's a self correcting problem in my experience after a number of hours. I just deploy the damn things after business hours or change the Guid during business hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per other comments, this has two potential solutions.

1. Waiting it out will sometimes clear up this issue after a number of
   hours. I deploy non-critical web parts after business hours.
2. Change the Guid and redeploy such as here:
   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-multiple-instance-of-spfx-webpart-in-same-app-catalog/